# CSS or jQuery : How to get visible top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a need to make a hidden div element shown in an user event, in the visible top.

What I  mean by visible top is,
- Its 0 if page is not scrolled
- if page is scrolled then I need coordinate of visible top, not the page top

Can that be set static with CSS or how to calculate it with jQuery or pure js.

Best Regards

Comment: `position: fixed`?

Comment: @raina77ow : I have  tried iwth 'fixed' yes. But anything works fit for me.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Thanks, Ill go through it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just plain `css`:

```
div {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   display: none;
}
```

This will always be on `top: 0` regardless of whether it is scrolled or not.

Comment: actually I need to adjust divs top ito top of screen after scrolling

Comment: `position: fixed` should work. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: yes it did work, thanks a lot.